# Free versioning server

Tags: svn, git, version-control, hg

I know services like GitHub and BitBucket, but I need even a little but private space to do versioning (doesn't really matters if it's git, hg or svn).
Years ago I subscribed to a service that gave me 200mb max storage and a private SVN repository.

Are there still services like this? What are the advantages and disadvantages of them?

Currently most known services like github, bitbucket, sourceforge, googlecode are free for open source projects, but I can't find something similar for "private" projects.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't install the software yourself?

Comment: Some of the information is now out of date, but you might find a question of mine on stack overflow last year might give you some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064945/42473

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BitBucket actually has free hosting for private projects with up to 5 users. Their pricing model is based on the number of collaborators only. I've got a 300 MB + private repo hosted in one account for work, and a number of smaller private repos in another personal account, with no dramas at all.

GitHub is good and I use it for a few open source projects, but they don't have free private repos. That said if you find a good service the cost really isn't that big for the benefits you get, and GitHub has a nicer interface than BitBucket IMO (Git vs Mercurial debates notwithstanding).

Comment: thanks a lot, i didn't noticed that with BitBucket private repos where free too, i know that they're not expensive at all, but at the moment i need it free :)

Comment: Yeah I didn't actually notice until I had my credit card out and realised they didn't want my money anyway :-)